# How to retrieve a saved image using its name?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I'm currently saving an image using `FileManager` like this:

```swift
guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
let fileName = imageName
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else { return }

do {
    try data.write(to: fileURL)
} catch let error {
    print("error saving file with error", error)
}
```

How do I retrieve this very file using the name of the file along the similar line as following?

```swift
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("fileName") {
    let filePath = pathComponent.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    // ??
} else {
    print("file not available")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same URL related API like in the `save` code

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileName = "fileName.jpg"
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path) {
    // do something with the image
} else {
    print("error loading file")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `UIImage` you could use [`init(contentsOfFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init) [`init(data:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624106-init) or [`init(data:scale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624109-init)